# I am trying to resolve the data fetched from a firebase query but the data is not getting resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I am trying to fetch the data from firebase through node but the data is not being resolved. I cant get the data i want. Basically i want the timestamp from the firebase data but cannot get it.

I have already tried to resolve it using promise and foreach function but no good.

```
router.post("/date", (req, res) => {
  const date = {
    sdate: req.body.sdate,
    edate: req.body.edate
  };
  let s = new Date(date.sdate).getTime();
  let e = new Date(date.edate).getTime();
  const coll = db
    .collection("calls")
    .where("time", ">=", `${s}`)
    .where("time", "<=", `${e}`)
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      doc.forEach(data => {
        console.log(data.id, data.data());
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  console.log(coll);
```

I expect to resolve the data into simple object or array so i can render it to the template engine to show the data.

Comment: I am getting the data but not able to parse it to the template engine , bcoz i cannot resolve the data in simple format. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Which line is giving output that you do not expect?

Comment: What is the schema of the calls collection?

Comment: The line in which data.data() is logged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you are trying to get [multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection). Your code example is confusing due to variable names not matching their meaning.

It is also unclear in your question which piece of your code sample is failing to produce the expected outcome but I suspect it is the `console.log(coll)`. This is because you are [returning nothing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value) inside your `.then()` and you are not waiting for the promise to be resolved before logging.

```
router.post("/date", (req, res) => {
  const date = {
    sdate: req.body.sdate,
    edate: req.body.edate
  };
  let s = new Date(date.sdate).getTime();
  let e = new Date(date.edate).getTime();
  const coll = []
  db
    .collection("calls")
    .where("time", ">=", `${s}`)
    .where("time", "<=", `${e}`)
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        coll.push({id: doc.id, data: doc.data()});
      });
      console.log(coll);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
})
```

Comment: Can I suggest accepting the answer if you are happy with it?